# How to get Vertex from provided attribute / key in Titan

Tags: java, titan

I am following code on Titan Documentation [GraphOfTheGodsFactory source code](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan05/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java) I want to retrieve a vertex from the graph, given some specified value / key / attribute.

I searched on documentation (I am using Titan 0.5.2), and tried using different functions, they provide null when executed.

Things I tried,

```
    `TitanManagement mgmt = graph.getManagementSystem();
    final PropertyKey userid = mgmt.makePropertyKey("userid").dataType(Integer.class).make();
    TitanGraphIndex namei = mgmt.buildIndex("userid",Vertex.class).addKey(userid).unique().buildCompositeIndex();  
    TitanTransaction tx = graph.newTransaction();
    Vertex ver1 = tx.addVertexWithLabel("user");
    ver1.setProperty("userid", "2");
    ver1.setProperty("username", "abc");
    Vertex found = graph.getVertex("2");`
```

found returns null.

Please help!

Comment: What's the full stack trace you get when you return null?

Comment: There's no exception. If I print the value of found, it prints null. `System.out.println(found);` -> null

Whereas if I print the value of ver1, `System.out.println(ver1);` It prints v[256]

Answer (score 4):

You can't find a `Vertex` this way:

```
Vertex found = graph.getVertex("2");
```

That method looks a vertex up by id, but there is no vertex in the graph with the id of "2" that is a String.  Now, because you have `ver1`, you do know the actual id of that `Vertex` so you can do:

```
Vertex found = graph.getVertex(ver1.getId());
```

Typically, you don't always have that identifier so you want to look things up by your domain data and the indices that you've created.  In that case you do:

```
Vertex found = graph.getVertices("userid","2").next();
```

That will do an index lookup on your `userid` property. Since that actually returns an `Iterator` you have to `next()` off the result.  Obviously, in this case, this only returns one result so no worries about anything else in the `Iterator` but you should probably account for that in some way in some real code.

Comment: for Tittan1.0 it `graph.vertices(userId);`